# Vector unknown size

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, header-files

I have a class Player which contains an instance variable: \

```
vector<Card> userCards;
```

In order to avoid any compilation errors I forward declared the class `Card`. However now when I try to Build Solution I get an error saying

> Card *: Unknown size.

Basically I am trying to create a `Player` who contains a non-fixed number of cards, so I tried using a vector and now I cannot get it to work.

Player.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

class Card;
class Player {
private:
    vector<Card> userCards;
};
#endif
```

Card.h

```
#include <iostream>

using std::string;

#ifndef CARD_H_
#define CARD_H_

class Card {
private:
    string name;
    string type;

public:
    Card(const string& name, const string& type);   
};
#endif
```

I have a bunch of different functions that are not related, so I did not include them.

Comment: Forward declarations can only be used with pointers, not when using the object type itself.

Comment: @Barmar untrue, class declarations can be used for a variety of purposes

Comment: @M.M According to my knowledge Barmar is correct, you can forward declare the class but when you refer to that class it must be a pointer or reference, not the object by itself: thus 'Card*' works but not 'Card'

Comment: @TheBadger [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container.html) are some containers that work with incomplete type (could be used in OP's code instead of `std::vector`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type template argument of `std::vector` cannot be an incomplete type. It has to be defined (complete) before instantiation of `std::vector<Card>`. To do that, replace your forward declaration `class Card;` with `#include "Card.h"` directive.

You can see the further requirements on template arguments [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you included the **Card.h** header in the **Player.h** file using the `#include "Card.h"` directive

but, if you did not then be informed that `std::vector<T>` requires its parameter to be a complete type and you cannot pass a forward declared type as its template argument.

Here is a another question/answer that clarifies your problem: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

The vector doesn't have to know how many cards you want to store, but is has to know the *size* of a `Card`.

So don't forward declare, but `#include` the Card.h.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<Card>` needs to see a complete declaration of `Card`. There are some certain functions that are needed for instantiation.

You can do something like a

```
vector<unique_ptr<Card>> userCards;
```

though, which behaves as any pointer (reference) declaration, and accepts the forward declaration.